# Htaccess 404 - redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

If someone requests a page that doesnt exist, for example if its

```
site.com/blabla/?search=blabla
```

with using this htacess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

They're being redirected to homepage with the same url, `site.com/blabla/?search=blabla`
What I want to do is, to redirect them to an IP, instead of the homepage. Tried this;

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://64.233.185.94/
```

But it just redirects to `http://64.233.185.94/`
I want to redirect it with the not found url, so it should redirect to

```
http://64.233.185.94/blabla/?search=blabla
```

at this point.

What is the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a `mod_rewrite` rule instead of `ErrorDocument` for that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=64.233.185.94
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://64.233.185.94/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Have you tried it ? It makes infinite redirect loop

Comment: It can cause infinite loop ONLY if `64.233.185.94` is IP of the same host where redirect was made. Is that indeed the case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use mod_rewrite to accomplish this. With mod_rewrite you can test if a requested file or directory exists, and if they do not exist you can do an external redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILNEMAE} !-d
RewriteRule ^ http://64.233.185.94%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Change the `R` flag to `R=301` after testing that this works as expected.

Comment: whats the difference of R and R=301, does it important ? or its just for search engines ?

Comment: 301 redirects are permanent as hjpotter linked. By using a permanent redirect clients can expect that redirect to never change, which means they can (permanently) cache the second url and load the second url on any subsequent request to the first url. For search engines this will prevent being penalized for duplicate content.